# magento 2 createBlock from argument item

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.2, blocks

My custom module xml file contains the block code. I want to call that block code directly using createBlock method and set template to show in specific template. My block code is adding animated fancing lines to form.

If i mention in xml using following format then it works fine. How can i display same block using **createBlock** method?

```
<referenceContainer name="form.contact.additional.info">
        <block class="Jackson\Wyss\Block\Frontend\Wyss" name="Wyss-reca" after="-"
               template="Jackson_Wyss::wyss.phtml">

            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="wyssdata" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Jackson_Wyss/js/reca</item>
                            <item name="zone" xsi:type="string">contact</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

**for example:**

```
 $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Jackson\wyss\Block\Frontend\Reca')->setData('jsLayout', '5')->setTemplate('goodtest/test.phtml')->toHtml();
```

In above xml code zone is form type name. I want to set different name for all the forms in createBlock method. is there anyway we can createBlock method for above xml code?

How can i make createBlock method of my above xml code?

Comment: You can try using as childblock. Add this block as as child where in you want to call and then call using getChildBlock

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So if i call it using the childBlock will it consider the paramaters defined under the (in your example)<item name="instant-purchase" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_InstantPurchase/js/view/instant-purchase</item>
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">

I want to make sure that in zone (in my code) applied there.

Comment: Yes it do. I have used it as mentioned in below code. YOu can try and let me know if in case of any issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using calling as ChildBlock, like the bellow example:

```
<!-- Add Instant purchase on Recently viewed products -->
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related" >
        <block name="product.info.addtocart.instantPurchase.additional.recently" class="Magento\InstantPurchase\Block\Button" template="Magento_InstantPurchase::button.phtml" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="instant-purchase" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_InstantPurchase/js/view/instant-purchase</item>
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_InstantPurchase/instant-purchase</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

In parent .phtml:

```
<?php
   if($block->getChildBlock('product.info.addtocart.instantPurchase.additional.recently', true))
  {
                                                    $block->getChildBlock('product.info.addtocart.instantPurchase.additional.recently')->setProduct($_product);

 echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.addtocart.instantPurchase.additional.recently', false);
}
```

?>